# How to print two Google Charts in one PNG image?

Tags: html, charts, google-visualization, xhtml

I'm writting a code which shows two different Google Charts in one XHTML page. I need to put a button that export both graphs to the same PNG file, one above the other as they are shown.

To export one single chart is easy and is already done; Google documentation teaches that in [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing) with only minor adjustments needed to show the button (done). The question now is how do I pick the information of both charts and print in the same PNG file.

I've considered a solution similar to the one shown in [this link](http://www.dannyoosterveer.nl/how-to-save-google-charts-visualizations-to-an-image-file-in-a-user-friendly-way/): pick the underlying canvas behind both images and tell to print that instead of the graphs per se. Problem is I have no idea how to do that and if that is even possible, even though a thread here in SO suggested something similar, suggesting it's possible, without going into the details on how to do it.

So how could I do that? I'm completely new to this web programming, so I'd be grateful for complete answers.

Comment: you can use [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) -- convert element that contains both charts to a canvas, then pull the image from the canvas -- [here is a recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062651/5090771) for one chart that shows `html2canvas`