# Highcharts: Custom Created SVG is not exported in the Highchart

Tags: svg, charts, highcharts

We drawing threshold bar on chart after chart creation, but it is not being exported in any format.[ThresholdBar draw in the right side of the chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRXzD.png)

```
drawThresholdBar: function(chart, config, parentSvg) {
    if (config.from !== config.to) {
        var me = this;
        var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
        var yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];
        var barWidth = 6;
        var barXPos = xAxis.toPixels(xAxis.max) + barWidth / 2;
        var fromPos = yAxis.toPixels(Ext.isNumeric(config.from) && config.from > yAxis.min ? config.from : yAxis.min) + 1;
        var toPos = yAxis.toPixels(Ext.isNumeric(config.to) && config.to < yAxis.max ? config.to : yAxis.max) - 1;
        var thresholdBarItem = chart.renderer
            .path(['M', barXPos, fromPos, 'L', barXPos, toPos])
            .attr({
                'stroke-width': barWidth,
                stroke: config.color
            })
            .add(parentSvg);
       }
},
```

We are storing threshold bar SVG in the thresholdBarItem.

Is there any way to push thresholdBarItem svg in chart config ? or any other way I can export it while exporting the chart.

Comment: Please add a live demo for the problem. This depends on where are you adding the custom element. If you will do that in the chart's callback or load event then it should be also visible in the exported chart.

Comment: you could try using `html2canvas` or manually drawing the svg to a canvas, which allows you to export using a data url. [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062651/5090771) of both...